# how to make redmine reload local .yml files

Tags: ruby, redmine

Good afternoon all,

Does anyone know how to reload a changed locale file in Redmine? In this case /redmine/config/locales/en-GB.yml

I traced the application through to see what was happening, but I'm no Ruby expert and couldn't find the answer. After first noticing that changes to these files do not take effect, I assumed the data was copied to another file or moved into the database but can't find anything to prove that theory.

Or if anyone has a better idea for doing some basic term/phrase replacement - then please let me know :)

Thanks in advance

Edit: For anyone that finds this. You restart redmine by either restarting your webserver or mongrel etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It loads the locales files when the app starts up. If you made changes, just restart the app.